# Increase performance for array manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using as certain code in JavaScript where I have to append a huge amount of data such as 10000 objects at a time to an array, and in a click event I again empty that array and reload that array with 10000 objects. Here is my code snippet:

where "Nodes" is an array populated from user datasource.

```
 var Index = 0;
    var _array = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.Nodes.length; i++) {
if(this.Nodes.PLeft>this.Nodes.Cleft){
        var temp = {};
        temp["PLeft"] = this.Nodes.PLeft;
        temp["CLeft"] = this.Nodes.CLeft;
        temp["PWidth"] = this.Nodes.PWidth;
        temp["CWidth"] = this.NodesCWidth;
        temp["PTop"] = this.Nodes.PTop;
        temp["CTop"] = this.Nodes.CTop;
        temp["Height"] = this.Nodes.Height;
        _array[Index++] = temp;
    }
    }
```

This works fine with Firefox, but for IE and Chrome the performance is too bad -- sometimes the browser crashes. I have also used `push()` method for array, but I did not find much difference in the performance. Does anyone have any idea on how to improve performance of array manipulation?

Comment: Did you just overwrite the `Array` constructor??? :O

Comment: Nope , I used to empty that array and then reload it , by declaring as an empty object.

Comment: He's saying that the variable name `Array` is not a good choice at all.

Comment: @joe_Benito The JavaScript Array global object is a constructor for arrays https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: In the above, `this` is the global object (aka window in a browser). What is it really?

Comment: What do you need those objects for? If you told us more about them, we might help you to reduce their number. Or you might be able to construct them lazily.

Comment: @joe_Benito—you haven't declared `Array` at all, you are creating it as a property of the global object at the point you do the assignment (unless there's code you aren't showing us and it's a local variable somewhere).

Comment: Why not reuse the `i` variable for the final array index? The second incrementing variable `Index` is redundant.

Comment: Also it seems to me that you're making an object out of an object and then putting it in the array...?

Comment: try `_array.push(temp)` instead of `_array[Index++] = temp;`

Comment: @Chris ,@Qantas sorry it was misspelled here and its not Array constructor I am using.

Comment: Why not just use `this.Nodes`? Do you really need to copy all that into new objects?

Comment: You're not dereferencing `this.Nodes` as an array before accessing the properties, so you will likely get all `undefined` values.

Comment: Use Typed Arrays and convert your object to a "structure" that you write directly to the typed array.

Comment: One big issue with this question is that the code within it doesn't make much sense on its own.  The meaning of `this` is unclear, for example, and `this.Nodes` is treated very oddly.  It'd help to see what that object looks like.

Comment: Hey @cHao "Nodes" is collection used to maintain user datasource and is populated by the user

Comment: @joe_Benito: Don't *tell* me. *Show* me.  Your code is already doing something odd...which in itself casts some doubts on your assertions about what it's doing.  The best way to clear that up is to see the code, not hear about it secondhand.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues here. First, your loop does not access the individual elements of `this.Nodes`. Because you keep referring to `this.Nodes.PLeft` (for example), you wind up with the same probably-undefined value. You must specify the index, `this.Nodes[idx].PLeft`.

This, of course, begs the question: **why do you need to loop some array and turn it into... an array**? Can't you just use `this.Nodes` directly instead of transferring it all into `_array` first?

Another thing: to reduce the weight of a loop, get the max length outside of the loops conditional statement. Doing it within the conditional causes that value to be looked up every time, by putting it into a variable the lookup only happens once.

You can eliminate the `temp` object and add the new array element directly. Likewise, you can eliminate the redundant counter and use the `for...` loop's counter.

```
var _array = [];
var maxlen = this.Nodes.length;
for (var idx = 0; idx < maxlen ; idx++) {
    if(this.Nodes[idx].PLeft > this.Nodes[idx].Cleft){
        // use idx for the array key IF you want it to match with this.Nodes indexes
        // if you don't care, use _array.length
        _array[_array.length] = {
            'PLeft':this.Nodes[idx].PLeft,
            'CLeft':this.Nodes[idx].CLeft,
            'PWidth':this.Nodes[idx].PWidth,
            'CWidth':this.Nodes[idx].CWidth,
            'PTop':this.Nodes[idx].PTop,
            'CTop':this.Nodes[idx].CTop,
            'Height':this.Nodes[idx].Height
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi chris , actually I have to check some conditions with "Nodes" array , and need to load a specific datas to the other array .

Comment: @joe_Benito I don't follow... but with the details you've provided here, this entire exercise seems pointless. Oh well, hope the code helped.

Comment: @joe_Benito Added the conditional you just edited into your question :)

Comment: This will leave holes in the array for when the condition was falsy :)

Comment: @Jack true, true, thanks for pointing that out. joe_Benito -- NB

Comment: @Jack—the OP likely wants `_array[idx]` to be equivalent to `Nodes[idx]`, there doesn't seem to be any other way of maintaining equivalence. Whether that is important or not is anyone's guess.

Comment: @RobG Tbh, it's anyone's guess what OP really wants :)

Comment: @joe_Benito I don't understand a word you just said. Jack, +5000. I'm out.